# subdomain doesn't exists anymore

Tags: subdomain

I haved a hosting account at godaddy(linux deluxe) and I just added a subdomain on one of my domains using the godaddy user interface.

I've added the subdomain 1hour ago, and the browser had find it. I've added some test files on it(phps and various html files) and all worked fine.

Now If i go to that subdomain, I'm redirected to google search. Has anyone an idea about what is happening? Which can be the cause of this result(non existing subdomain in browser oppinion)?

PS: also, I've deleted google.html(file size 0k) because I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably DNS not catching up to the change yet. It used to take up to 72 hours in the past, but is down to a few hours these days for DNS changes to make it around all the various DNS servers.